# BigCommerce / SkyVia Sql data integration

Tags: sql, bigcommerce

I need to export from SQL Server 2016 table of shipped orders to the BigCommerce OrderShipments table.

BC API requires the Order line items as an array object.

I have set the SQL table `items` column data type to `nvarchar(max)`.

This is then final `items` array in my SQL shipped orders table

```
[
   {“order_product_id”:16,“product_id”:1920,“quantity”:1},
   {“order_product_id”:17,“product_id”:1921,“quantity”:1}
]
```

This fails with an error

Is this array text correct, any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the product_id field is read-only, have you tried removing this field? Could you also share the error you're seeing after making this request? I've included an example request I made that worked on a sandbox below.

Sent as a POST request to /v2/orders/{order_id}/shipments:

```
{
    "order_address_id":"1",
    "shipping_provider":"",
    "items": [
        {
            "order_product_id": 1,
            "quantity":1
        },
        {
            "order_product_id": 2,
            "quantity":1
        }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Kyle Thanks for the answer . The format shown is as documented by BigCommerce so the Product_ID is required in the export. I tried removing the underscores form the column names, changing to lower case to no avail. There is no error message delivered by the SkyVia intergration connection , just "Failed", BidCommerce support say this is a SkyVia problem so now I have three service providers involved if what appears to be the simplest of problems and all I am getting is emails promising to look into the isses and to "Have a great day" Thanks Again